# What is the value of $\alpha +\beta$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, physics

> **If $U=f(P,V,T)$ be the internal energy of a gas that obeys the ideal gas law $PV=nRT$, ($n$ and $R$ constants)
>   and$(\frac{∂U}{∂T})_v+(\frac{∂U}{∂P})_v=α(\frac{∂U}{∂T})+β(\frac{∂U}{∂P})$then
>   α+β equals**
>
> (A)$2+\frac{v}{nR}+\frac{nR}{v}$
>
> (B)$1+\frac{v}{nR}$
>
> (C)$1+\frac{n}{Rv}$
>
> (D) 1

Let us take $U\equiv PV-nRT$,then $(\frac{∂U}{∂T})_v+(\frac{∂U}{∂P})_v=α(\frac{∂U}{∂T})+β(\frac{∂U}{∂P})\implies -nR+V=-\alpha nR +\beta V$

on comparing coefficient of both sides we get $\alpha=1$ and $\beta =1$.So,$\alpha +\beta =2$

But it does not matches with  none of the option.

> Where i'm commiting mistake??

Comment: Why do you define $U=PV-nRT$? Since $PV=nRT$, by your definition $U\equiv 0$.

Comment: @rafa11111:Since,U is any function of $P,V,T$,so i chose this relation...Is it not correct??If NOT,then what  is the rule for choosing the  function?

Comment: I think that you can not choose *any* relation by your taste... in thermodynamics the internal energy is defined as $U\equiv c n T$, in which $c$ is the molar specific heat of the gas being considered. In that case, it seems to me that $\alpha=1$. However, I can not see a way to prove that using only calculus, without knowing the physics involved in the question.

Comment: Consider using the chain rule. Since $U$ is a function of $P,V,T$ and $P,V,T$ are related, we can rewrite $\left ( \frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\right )_V$ in terms of $\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}$ and $\frac{dP}{dT}$ or vice versa